# automapper: Mapping from an array to one field?

Tags: c#, automapper

I am having an issue trying to map an array to a type. I get the following error

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Run[] -> Run
```

The destination item is a Run and the source is a Run (array of)....  I setup my mappings in global.asax

```
   Mapper.CreateMap<Model.Run, Run>();
```

Any ideas, I think I am missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AutoMapper can automatically map collection-to-collection when you have specified the type mapping, so when you have:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Model.Run, Run>();
```

you can just go with

```
var runs = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Model.Run>, IEnumerable<Run>>(source);
```

because it follows naturally - it maps every item of the source collection to destination collection using the one-to-one map you have specified. What doesn't follow is automatic `T -> T[]` or `T[] -> T` mapping, what should the mapper do when you map `T[] -> T`? Take the first item from array? Or maybe the last one? Do some kind of aggregation? What if the collection is empty?

You have to write a separate, full map for that, e.g:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Model.Run[], Run>()
      .ForMember(x => x.NumericMember, expr => expr.MapFrom(y => y.Sum(z => z.NumericMember)))
      .ForMember(//etc...);
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what i was looking for creatmap with an array and non array, didn't realize you could do this. Yes, the array should only ever contain 1 item or 0 ... hence the destination object should be NULL or contain the item from source form element @ position 0

Comment: @Martin There's nothing standing in your way, when you explicitly and fully specify your map, you can map anything (or almost anything) :)